# Disable Laravel Pluralization For Person To People

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called *agency_persons* with some data already in it. I created a model using *php artisan*:

```
php artisan make:model AgencyPerson
```

Now when I try to use Laravel's Eloquent methods i face following error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'my_database.agency_people' doesn't

Laravel is looking for people table instead of persons.

I know Laravel is trying to do the right thing and I should have named my table *agency_people* in the first place, but I cannot change name of the table, because other applications are using this table too.
How can I disable laravel's pluralization for person to people?

Comment: You don't have to use artisan commands to make files; in this case, I would copy an existing `model` and change the properties to that of your `AgencyPerson`; specifically the `protected $table` property. Of, if the model was already created successfully, all you have to do is edit that property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the model, add the line

```
 protected $table = 'agency_persons';
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent for more details, look for section Tablenames

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using persons table and person model in laravel. Laravel Pluralization For Person To People will give you this error whatever your query would be:-
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lrv_db.people' doesn't exist (SQL: select `posts`.*, `people`.`country_id` from `posts` inner join `people` on `people`.`id` = `posts`.`person_id` where `people`.`country_id` = 1)'
```

**Solution for this is :-
Define your table in the person model as below:**

```
class person extends Model
{
    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'persons';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else stumbling into this problem the pluralization of names is handled by the Doctrine Project, and the rules applied are on the Inflectible class (\Doctrine\Inflector\Rules\English)

More info:

https://medium.com/@kipropesque/deep-dive-into-how-the-laravel-framework-does-pluralization-7146a0202505

https://www.doctrine-project.org/

https://github.com/doctrine/annotations

Answer (score -2):

You can also define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable. You may do this using the $fillable property on the model.
Example:

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'description'];
```

Once you have made the attributes mass assignable, you can use the create method to insert a new record in the database.
The use of $fillable to protect which fields you want this to actually allow for updating.

Comment: While useful advice, this has literally nothing to do with the question being asked here...

Comment: I just tried to add some useful informations for him ;)